# How to load image by clicking on button in TornadoFX?

Tags: image, kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

It works this way, but it puts the image in the button. Also I need to manipulate the image later, so somehow I need to save it in an Image variable.

```
class MainView : View("FilterApp") {

override val root = vbox {
    val inputTextField = textfield { }
    var imageBox = imageview(){}

    button("Click me") {
        action {
            imageBox = imageview(Image(inputTextField.getText()))
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is this kotlin?

Comment: Yes, it is kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

got it

```
class MainView : View("FilterApp") {

private lateinit var mainImage: Image

override val root = vbox {
    val inputTextField = textfield { }
    var imageBox = imageview(){}

    button("Click me!") {
        action {
            mainImage = Image(inputTextField.getText())
            imageBox.image = mainImage
        }
    }
}
}
```